# Calculate coefficient for all subsets of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lm, coefficients

I want to calculate the correlation coefficient of weight and time for each individual in a data frame separately. The data frame consists of about 40 individuals, with 10 or fewer observations per individual. I have been able to calculate the coefficient for individuals separately, but not to get R to do it for the lot in one go.

My data look something like this:

```
id <- c(rep(1, times = 10), rep(3, times = 10), rep(4, times = 10))
time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
weight <- runif(30, min = 50, max = 100)
dataframe <- data.frame(id, time, weight)
```

I have had success calculating the coefficient for separate individuals using this function:

```
coef(lm(weight~time, data = dataframe))[2]
```

I have tried `for-loops`, `aggregate` and `apply`, but can't figure out how to calculate the coefficient for all individuals in one go and store the outputs as a vector.

Comment: You should show what you have tried (especially with `aggregate`), that will help us help you better.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but you use can do somethig like: 
`df %>%  split(.$id) %>%  map(cor)`. Before do that, do `library(tidyverse)`.

Comment: What I have tried is
`aggregate(desiccation_clean, by = list(id), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)` and the apply I tried was `test <- desiccation_clean[,lapply(.SD, mean), by = id]`

Both did not work. The split() as suggested by zx8754 comes very close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*split* by id, then loop through and get *coef*:

```
sapply(split(dataframe, dataframe$id), function(i) coef(lm(weight ~ time, data = i))[2])
#     1.time      3.time      4.time 
# 1.48800159 -0.05921987 -2.57523482
```